Insurance and finance contract datasets
I am pursuing an NER related task for which I would need collections of contracts in the domains of insurance and finance. The data does not have to be annotated (but if it is, this would be a plus) and it can be in e.g. pdf format. I am looking for at least 50 documents per collection. I would also welcome any suggestions on platforms/websites that have or point to datasets like this. Thank you.
